# Parallax scrolling in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have trouble implementing parallax scrolling in a background image in React, any help would be appreciated.

The error I get is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

```js
function Hero() {
  const parallax = document.getElementById('home');
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    let offset = window.pageYOffset;
    parallax.style.backgroundPositionY = offset * .12 + 'px';
  })
  return (
    <div className="hero-container" id='home'>
      <p className='title'>The Burger Shop</p>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Hero
```

```css
.hero-container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('burger2.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: The element doesn't exist yet when you try to select it. See [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: You can do this with pure css too. No framework-specific code is required for this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp. `background-attachment: fixed; background-size: cover;` do the trick. So in your case setting the `backgroundPositionY` through javascript isn't necessary.

Comment: @Pieterjan that is not the same effect though, as the one in the code. The OP wants the image to move in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2):

The element is not yet mounted at the time you run the `getElementById`.

You will need to use a `ref` (*with [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)*) and you will also need to remove the event listener once the element is un-mounted. You will need [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) for this

```js
function Hero() {
  const parallax = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    function scrollHandler() {
      const element = parallax.current;
      if (element) {
        let offset = window.pageYOffset;
        element.style.backgroundPositionY = offset * .12 + 'px';
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
    // return the function to remove the handler
    // which will be run whn Hero is unmounted
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="hero-container" id='home' ref={parallax}>
      <p className='title'>The Burger Shop</p>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Hero
```

Demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-water-fx5rb